# Closing a html/css hamburger menu causes menu link misalignment

Tags: html, css

When I click on X button and the menu starts collapsing, menu links jump to the left top corner and then disappear.
[This image illustrates this weird behavior.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5z7hU.png)

Code:

```
    <header>
<menu>
  <div class="flex-wrapper-menu">
    <div class="left-menu">
      <ul class="menu-links">
        <li><a href="#">Ekaterina Vernigorova</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

      <div class="menu-logo" id="top"><a href="#"></a></div>

    <div class="right-menu">
      <input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle">
      <ul class="menu-links" id="mobile-hamburger">
        <li><a href="index.html">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
      </ul>
      <label for="menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle-label">
        <span></span>
      </label>
    </div>

  </div>
</menu>
```

```
    @media (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 767px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  .flex-wrapper-menu {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .left-menu {
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  .right-menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
  }

  #menu-toggle {
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  .menu-toggle-label {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .menu-toggle-label span,
  .menu-toggle-label span::before,
  .menu-toggle-label span::after {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: black;
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5px;
  }

  .menu-toggle-label span::before,
  .menu-toggle-label span::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
  }

  .menu-toggle-label span::before {
    bottom: 7px;
  }

  .menu-toggle-label span::after {
    top: 7px;
  }

  ul#mobile-hamburger {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background: white;
    transform: scale(1,0);
    transform-origin: top;
    transition: transform 400ms ease-in-out;
  }

  ul#mobile-hamburger li {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }

  ul#mobile-hamburger li a {
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 150ms ease-in-out ;
  }

  .menu-links li + li {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  #menu-toggle:checked ~ ul#mobile-hamburger {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transform: scale(1,1);
  }

  #menu-toggle:checked ~ .menu-toggle-label span {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }

  #menu-toggle:checked ~ .menu-toggle-label span::before {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    bottom: 0;
  }

  #menu-toggle:checked ~ .menu-toggle-label span::after {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    top: 0;
  }

  #menu-toggle:checked ~ ul#mobile-hamburger a {
    opacity: 1;
    /* transition comes with a delay when the menu is checked */
    transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out 250ms;
  }
}
```

Live website: https://ekaterinavernigorova.github.io/portfolio/

I know that people usually use java script for hamburger menus, but since I'm not familiar with it, I tried html and css only menu.

It's my first web coding project, and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem are these lines of your css code:

```
 ul#mobile-hamburger {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background: white;
    transform: scale(1,0);
    transform-origin: top;
    transition: transform 400ms ease-in-out;
  }
```

```
  #menu-toggle:checked ~ ul#mobile-hamburger {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transform: scale(1,1);
  }
```

You apply the flex layout to the menu only if the checkbox is `:checked`, so once the checkbox is unchecked the `flex` layout is removed, resulting in your observed behavior.

You need to move the flex layout to the `ul#mobile-hamburger` rule.

```
 ul#mobile-hamburger {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background: white;
    transform: scale(1,0);
    transform-origin: top;
    transition: transform 400ms ease-in-out;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

```
  #menu-toggle:checked ~ ul#mobile-hamburger {
    transform: scale(1,1);
  }
```